# Rails 4 - Pushing to Heroku issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

thanks for looking @ this.  It's relatively simple issue I believe.  A little long of a post just so you all have any information you might need to know about my setup and pushing to Heroku.
I am following this guide.
http://docs.railsbridge.org/intro-to-rails/deploying_to_heroku.

I have this error:

```
To git@heroku.com:polar-thicket-3762.git                                                                                        
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)                                                               
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:polar-thicket-3762.git'
```

Which happens when I try to push to Heroku.  It tries to pre-compile assets.
Solutions have said that I need to add this line in my application.rb to have it successfully push which I have tried.

```
ruby config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
```

It does succesfully push, but then it won't compile the database via

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```

Then when I try to run that command, it says it won't run rake db:migrate on thread .3309 due to "ruby" not being found.  I tried remove the ruby in front of it, and it then won't push to heroku.

How can I fix this by pushing to Heroku, and get it to compile the DB?
Thanks!

It would be helpful to know a few things, I'm using Nitrous.io and Sqlite3 for dev purposes.
My application.rb is as such (and also database.yml & gemfile is listed below)

APPLICATION.RB

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module RailsBase
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is UTC.
    config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de

    # To push to Heroku 
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
  end
end
```

DATABASE.YML -----------------------------------------------------------

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
#
default: &default
  adapter: sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  <<: *default
  database: db/production.sqlite3
```

GEMFILE ----------------------------------------------------------

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby "2.0.0"

gem 'rails', '4.1.6'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2'
gem 'puma'
gem 'thin'
gem 'bcrypt'

gem 'rmagick'
gem 'carrierwave'                   #to handle image uploads

# Push to heroku
# Look @ this site below for more instructions and look @ section "each time"
# http://docs.railsbridge.org/intro-to-rails/deploying_to_heroku

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

# Add for Heroku deployment to "production" which in my case is stage
group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end


# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
# gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
# gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer',  platforms: :ruby


# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano-rails', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your rails app is in the root of the repo, the Gemfile is present and properly named. It is basically not able to detect your code base as one of the supported project types and hence failing it. Also, even if your do have a proper project, make sure it is part of the repo and your have committed it fine (git status will help you here and a ls should help you verify the project structure)

Comment: Ok, git status is clean.  Also my app location is the root of the repo and i'm on master branch.  How is the application.rb, and did I put that command in correctly?